# Convert (B,G,R,IR) to (R,G,B) image arrays - Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have some satellite images, and I wanted to convert them to regular RGB images. The Satellite images are in the (B,G,R,IR) ranges. I want to convert them to (RGB images). Currently, I am doing the following:

```
    img1 = img[ :, :, :-1].copy()
    img1 = img1*255.0/img1.max()
    img2 = np.zeros(np.shape(img1))
    img2[:,:,0] = img1[:,:,2]
    img2[:,:,1] = img1[:,:,1]
    img2[:,:,2] = img1[:,:,0]
    img2 = img2.astype(np.uint8)
```

The above code looks positively ugly. I am wondering if there is some neat trick to doing this. Some form of `hstack`, `vstack` etc, Or some form of smart transpose ...

Comment: You refer to a previous "parse" of the images in your title, but from the body of your post that seems irrelevant. Maybe you should just title it "parse image iles" or, IMO more appropriate, "convert BGRI to RGB images efficiently"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `img1`, I would suggest keeping it as it is both from performance point of view and code compactness.

For `img2` creation, we are working on the third axis as the color dimension to basically flip along it, so we could shorten it like so -

```
img2 = img1[:,:,::-1].astype(np.uint8)
```

Comment: I guess `img[:, :, -2::-1]` could be faster because it avoids fancy indexing.

Comment: @kazemakase Yup! `img1[:,:,2::-1]` it would be, thanks for pointing it out!